# Get Linux device IP address from com port using PowerShell

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, serial-port, ip-address

I am currently setting up a test ARM based board running Linux and I need to access it from a Windows machine. This test board is connected via the com port using a USB-to-Serial cable. I am using PowerShell to run commands and control the test board.
I'm stuck at a stage where I need to query the test board to find out its IP Address and store it in a variable on my Windows host.

This is what I'm using to display the IP Address:

```bsh
$port.WriteLine("ifconfig | grep -A 1 'gphy' | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1")
```

When I read the output from the console, I get the `ifconfig` command as well as the IP Address into my variable:

```bsh
$ipAddr = $port.ReadExisting()
$ipAddr
```

The output is something like:

```sh
ifconfig | grep -A 1 'gphy' | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
123.33.33.150
#
```

I fail to get only the IP Address as a string. Is my approach correct or am I doing something wrong here? What is the best way for querying for the IP Address?

Comment: What is puzzling you? The fact that the variable also contains the entire command? How is `$port` defined/created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use either a substring or a regex to extract the value(s) you'd want.

```
$ipaddr = @"
ifconfig | grep -A 1 'gphy' | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
123.33.33.150
"@
$regex = '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
(($ipaddr | Select-String -Pattern $regex).Matches).Value
```

Results

```
123.33.33.150
```

Comment: This is by far the most simple way to do this.

Comment: @postanote I was wondering if I should take the regex route. Like everyone's suggested, this is by far the easiest way. Just to add to your answer, I will get my final IP Address in $matches[0]. This all but solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In ARM Linux, it will be possible to set echo off of the port connected to Windows.
For example, if the connection port is /dev/ttyS0, add the following line to startup script.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -echo
```

However, unless you change the setting, all the write data will not be echoed back in other uses.